# Will `generate-core-file` allow as much introspection and analysis as inspecting a "live" crash does?

Tags: debugging, gdb, coredump

I have a rare program crash captured inside GDB as I type this question. Unfortunately, all of the engineers likely to be able to help me figure out why the crash happened are asleep at the moment.

The crashed program in question happens to be Chromium, which adds an extra element: my PC is basically unusable right now, and I have no access to my tabs, etc.

If `generate-core-file` captures **everything** `gdb` knows right now about the "live" crashed Chromium process, I'll be able to clean up the crashed instance, restart, etc, and that would be *very* nice.

But if there's ***anything*** at all that `generate-core-file` misses, I definitely don't want to use it.

Should I be okay?

This is on 32-bit Linux (Slackware).

FWIW, I think the bug is in relation to thread management - the crash itself starts with >700 `pthread_create: Resource temporarily unavailable` messages, then the memory manager fails to allocate 8MB RAM, even though I have 223 times that much free right now, and many GBs of unused swap on top of that, so it's possible this is a race condition between many threads.

Comment: What operating system? (32 or 64 bits Linux?)

Comment: Whoops! 32-bit Linux (Slackware), kernel 4.1.6.

Comment: 32 bits Linux is becoming out of fashion. Can't you install a 64 bits distribution.... (and please **edit your question**, don't comment it)

Comment: Unfortunately not - I have no way to upgrade at the moment, and my PC is from 2006 (32-bit Pentium M, ThinkPad T43). Thanks for the mention of editing the question; I can never figure out when that's appropriate! Editing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But if there's anything at all that generate-core-file misses, I definitely don't want to use it.

There *definitely* are things that are possible in a live GDB session that are not possible with the `core`. The set of such things is very small, but not empty.

If you care about this particular crash so much, you should use `generate-core` and then *wait* for an engineer to tell you whether she cares about the live session or not.

Comment: This canonically answers my question, so I'm accepting it. In my case, some engineers woke up on IRC and helped me track the issue down (I was on a 32-bit machine and hit the virtual memory limit of 3GB!), and ***not*** killing `gdb` (and the frozen chromium processes) proved instrumental, as the chromium process that had been using 2.9GB of RAM at the time of the crash was still visible in `ps`, `htop`, etc.